# Bitmap.Save(...) generates different image than actual

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap

I've parsed an image with the following code

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("file.jpg");
```

And after saved so

```
img.Save("file2.jpg");
```

I did not modify anything, but looking on diff of the both images, I see that the new one is different. How I can fix that? I want to keep the colors

Comment: Do you use some non standard library? Where is `Canvas.FromFile()`?

Comment: No, standard. `System.Drawing`

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW, I write codes on C# very rare, I did not know there is any difference, sorry

Comment: Can't find anything like `System.Drawing.Canvas`

Comment: I missed with `Bitmap`, edited

Comment: The colors should not really change but saving without specifying the quality may well creat quite some differences! Look up the overload with jpeg encoder!

Comment: You did not use the Save() overload that specifies the ImageFormat.  So you actually got a PNG file.  Stored in a filename with the .jpg extension.  Yeah, like, don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant, I saved as jpeg now, but still a number of pixels is different. Tried these advices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218017/how-to-save-a-bitmap-image-as-jpeg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669850/high-quality-jpeg-compression-with-c-sharp