# How to convert the Data (Array´s List) into a Jpeg File or a Pdf or a Layout in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, jpeg

I'm a beginner in C# and I have  a Project to Finish.
I must read the certain data from XML file and convert it to JPEG or PDF , I have done the first Part of the project by reading the Data and putting it in Array's List , but I'm stuck now How to convert this List into a Layout or JPEG file .
I don't know where should I begin, I am grateful for your Ideas

Thank you All

Comment: what format has the data from the xml file? are you reading bytes?

Comment: Here is how to save a Bitmap in JPEG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218017/how-to-save-a-bitmap-image-as-jpeg

Comment: this question is actually too broad for SO, but we can give you directions and hints in the comments, if you provide more information and answer our questions. Don't be offended if the question gets closed soon. Welcome to StackOverflow